# C# - If statement query regarding variable name repetition

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement, repeat

Is there a more concise way to check if x is either "a","b","c","d" or "e"?

```
if (x == "a" | x == "b" | x == "c" | x == "d" | x == "e"){//do something}
```

Basically I want to know if I can express the same if statement without repeating the variable name x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
string[] whiteList = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

if(whiteList.Contains(x))
{
    ...
}
```

You can consider using a `HashSet<string>` or similar and caching a reference to it in a field for improved performance (to give you an `O(1)` Contains operation and to avoid allocating, populating the collection).

```
//Field
HashSet<string> _whiteList = new HashSet<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

....

// In a method:
if(_whiteList.Contains(x))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think you could also just shortcut to `new[]{"a","b"..."e"}.Contains(x)` no?

Comment: Or rather, (new[]...).Contains ... idk, I don't have an IDE open to test with, and rather not load one just for this.

Comment: @jcolebrand: You could, but that would create a new copy of the array each time. This approach allows a single array to be created once and reused.

Comment: @JonSkeet only if he caches it, right? As in, if he creates the `whiteList` var everytime this check is done, that would be the same as what I suggest?

Comment: @jcolebrand: Yes, in that case it would be the same.

Comment: Off the top of your head, do you recall which syntax is correct of the two I proposed?

Comment: Thank you. This serves my purpose well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be.aspx) on array of "a-d".

`new string[]{"a","b",...}.Exists(x)`

Comment: @jcolebrand: just corrected, cause first I make an example on `char` array.

Comment: Do you still need the leading `string`? I don't think you do.

Comment: @jcolebrand: sure you need it. How you gonna create a `string` array so?

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well, Tigran.

Comment: @Tigran because it interpolates the fact that it's a string since all the inner elements are strings?

Comment: @jcolebrand: ah ok I missunderstood your question.. In **real** code I *usually* skip it, but in examples tend to leave it, to clearly manifest my ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to check only characters, comparing the ascii code of characters could do it as under.

```
if(x >= 'a' && x <= 'e')
{

}
```

Comment: What if x is a unicode character? what if it's not something that boxes to an int?

Comment: Before down voting this please explain to me how this answers the question

Comment: I agree, I didn't think it was so bad as to need a downvote, but felt I should mention that ...

Comment: It is type casting the character to int and ascii code of a is 97 which code be used in condition

Comment: I didn't down vote it, but this doesn't answer his question. He was pretty much looking for the Contains method.

Comment: It's my fault I didn't specify that I was just showing an example. I do not intend to check for a range of characters only. Anyway, thanks and thumbs up for a correct answer, yet not what I looked for.

Comment: No worries, Thanks for taking care.